# What are the non-wheelsize settings on my Michelin F17 cyclocomputer?

Tags: bike-computer

I've got an old michelin speedometer(F17) for my bike and I've lost the manual (nothing on the web), I've had to replace the battery and now I have to redo the settings. I've already set up the tire size but eventually I get to this setting screen and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to set the values here. The values on the picture are the default.

Note : It's a wired speedometer with a magnet sensor.

[image: Michelin speedometer setting]

Comment: Most bike computers allow you to set (i.e restore) total distance and total time after a battery change. Maybe this is total average speed? Since it says 2.3km/h it has to be a speed. Or maybe it's some kind of threshold under which it considers you to be stationary (not counting to total time)?

Comment: @Michael , you make good point, it could very well be the threshold for stationary vs moving. But then I don't know what the bottom number is for which I can also change.

Comment: Seems the part number is 801953, whereas 801905 is a later wireless model.  I did find a multi-language version of the wireless manual here: 
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2026472/Michelin-801905.html?page=3  However its not super-helpful - hopefully this offers you a lead, if you can compare the pictures with your device.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That screen is requesting age and weight.  Weight is in either lbs/kg depending on if you set imperial/metric for distance measurement.

I was unable to find a manual for the 17 function computer, but here is a link to the manual for the 20 function version.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2026472/Michelin-801905.html?page=4#manual